# How do I get all CSS properties applied on any element in a webpage using JAVA?

Tags: java, html

I have a html page, with few CSS files, and JS. I want to list all CSS properties which are applied on a given #id in the html. This I want to do using Java. I can do it by writing code from scratch, but are there any Libraries which can do it easily?

Comment: What are you trying to do? use a Java program to 'scrape' the CSS content?

Comment: You can try `jsoup`

Comment: @eugen, That sounds like an answer!  Flesh it out and submit it as an answer so we can pass you some rep.

Comment: I literally hit submit as I noticed you commented @Eugen! :P

Comment: @Isac It is so often situation. Easy questions are answered very fast, it's like a race )

Comment: @Eugen slow and steady doesn't win the rep race! :P

Answer (score 2):

You can try [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/). It provides a very convenient API for working with HTML.
For get CSS properties try:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://en.wikipedia.org/").get();
Elements idElement= doc.select("#idElement");
Attributes attrs = idElement.attributes​();
attrs.asList​().stream().forEach( e -> {
    System.out.println(e.getKey​() + " :" + e.getValue​());
});
Set<String> = idElement.classNames​();
```

Answer (score 0):

I presume you mean you want to use a Java library, to scrape the content off of your web page. A good library to use would be [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax). The linked example shows you how to use the libraries syntax selector which sounds like what you want to do! More specifically you'll want to use the selector for #ID which targets the name of the ID you want!

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://example.com").get();
doc.select("#id").forEach(System.out::println);
```

Would print all of the ID div out. You can then also save these to a set if you want to.

You would first need to install Jsoup. Do so by clicking and following instructions  here [Download](https://jsoup.org/download)

Comment: Let say I have a div with id="hello", can you give a short code snippet, to get all css properties applied on this id?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use something like Selenium because you want all of the applied CSS properties and not the css class names.

http://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/how-to-get-css-values-using-webdriver